# Variables in cloned Scratch sprites - global or local?

Tags: mit-scratch

I am creating a falling snow background in Scratch and stumbled across the following code:

[image]

I then read the wiki on cloning sprites and was stumped at this sentence:

**Variables for all sprites will be the same for each clone, but variables for this sprite only will be different for each clone.**

**Question:**

In my *when clicked block* I create a clone of myself. Both the clone and the *when clicked block* share the variable **y pos** but they seem to be acting independently (thus in oops terms) a variable of type 'this' ie a separate variable instantiated only for the clone object. I cannot display it with a tick so I am assuming it is local to the clone?

Or is **y pos** global (a class variable)? I am guessing the latter but the sentence above is not helping.

Comment: Scratch's y axis is from -180 to 180, not -360 to 360 btw.

Comment: It is to slow down the animation

Comment: I spotted this myself but the animation halts half way down instead of the bottom of the screen - try it!

Answer (score 2):

A local variable in Scratch is also a seperate instance in each clone. A global variable only exists once and is the same for all objects. Scratch has no class variables, which would be shared among clones of the same object.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work properly, the variable ypos must be local (for this Sprite only), otherwise the two would interfere with each other.

Comment: That is what I found out by using the 'say statements' and I think it is local. I found the are affector clones and non-affector clones. Guess the reason for comments in other people's code is very important in Scratch or you will be scratching your head.

Answer (score 0):

The variable accessibility *will vary depending on how you create it*. When you create the variable in the variable menu (ie where you choose the name) it will ask you if you want the variable accessible by "all sprites" or "just this one". If you choose "all sprites," the variable will be created global, and will be accessible (and changeable) by all sprites. If you select "just this one," it should be created a local variable, and only be accessible by each sprite individually.

---

Hope I helped. -GreenHawk1220